# Off-By-One Error Calculating Expression Depth

Tags: python

I am new to python and am taking the [artificial intelligence course on MIT OpenCourseWare](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-034-artificial-intelligence-fall-2010/). I am working on the lab0 assignment, "Expression Depth" question for reference.

When I run my code, it is not taking the first `item` in the `expr` as a list even when it is, so the return value is 1 less than expected.

Code:

```
def depth(expr):
    d = 0
    for item in expr:
        print isinstance(item, (tuple, list))
        if isinstance(item, (tuple, list)):
            lvl = 1 + depth(item)
            if lvl >= d:
                d = lvl
    return d
```

A test is run with this argument:

```
def depth_2_getargs():
    return [['expt', 'x', 2]]
```

the answer here should be `d = 1`, but here is my output:

```
False
False
False
Test 10/23: Incorrect.
    depth_2
Got:      0
Expected: 1
```

So my personal interpretation is that, `isinstance(item, (tuple, list))` doesn't see the first element in `expr` as a list, rather `item` seems to have taken the first element in the sublist. The output should be

```
True
False
False
False
```

Right?  The initial `True` is from the supplied list; the three `False` lines are from iterating on the list elements.

Why does this happen, and how do I fix this?

EDIT: To clarify and save others trouble, the assignment states:

```
depth('x') => 0
depth(('expt', 'x', 2)) => 1
depth(('+', ('expt', 'x', 2), ('expt', 'y', 2))) => 2
depth(('/', ('expt', 'x', 5), ('expt', ('-', ('expt', 'x', 2), 1), ('/', 5, 2)))) => 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your code:

```
def depth(expr):
    d = 0
    for item in expr:
```

You *assume* that the given argument is an iterable of some sort (implied in the `for` statement), and you assign the default depth of that sequence as 0.  You got exactly what you programmed.  If a list is supposed to have an initial depth of 1, then start `d` at 1, not 0.

Otherwise, you might test `expr` to see whether it's a list/tuple; if not, return 0; if so, start `d` at 1 and loop through the elements (current loop logic).

Does that disambiguate your base case?

Try this introduction to the routine:

```
def depth(expr):
    if isinstance(item, (tuple, list)):
        d = 1
        for item in expr:
            lvl = 1 + depth(item)
            if lvl >= d:
                d = lvl
    else:
        d = 0
return d
```

This defers the base case to receiving a scalar (or string, etc.), which *does* have a depth of 0.  It also returns 1 for the depth of an empty list (which has no items through which to iterate).

Comment: The expected output seems to be consistent with a depth of 0 for a list containing no other lists or tuples. (That, or the questioner has misrepresented the test input.)

Comment: Initial depth of 0 is correct. Prune, I am not sure what you mean at the bottom there, sorry

Comment: "base case" is a term in recursion structure: it's the decision that returns a base result instead of recurring.

Comment: If initial depth of 0 is correct, then how do you expect to get a depth of 1 for a simple (not nested) list?  Each element is a scalar, you skip every iteration, and return 0 for the list depth.  In short, your code functionally defines the depth of a simple list as the default value of `d`.

Comment: The test input presented in the question is nested. (Whether this accurately reflects the real test input is unknown.)

Comment: No, I know that. I don't know what you mean by return 0 and if not start `d` at 1. Each recursive call will start the local depth of that recursive call at 0. Also, I am not assuming anything. The test cases and format have been provided if you follow the link and look at the assignment.

Comment: SO posting guidelines clearly state that your posting needs to stand alone.  "follow the link and look at the assignment" does not support archiving the question -- which, after all, is the stated purpose of SO.

Comment: Also, you *do* assume: `depth` will crash if `expr` is not an iterable.  I'll edit the code with my 0/1 suggestion; perhaps that will clarify the issue.

Comment: OK now you are extremely clear! :) thank you very much. Just before you edited your answer, I had figured out what you were getting at thanks to @user2357112. I had a very, very slight misunderstanding in the assignment. I accidentally saw the first example as a list, and from there my entire definition of the problem was wrong

Answer (score 1):

Maybe when they write return `[['expt', 'x', 2]]` they return a list of all the arguments to pass to your function, whish is only 1 in this case, so the argument they intend to pass is `['expt', 'x', 2]` and not `['expt', 'x', 2]`

Actually the output seems fine to me:

```
lorenzo@pc:~$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def depth(expr):
...     d = 0
...     for item in expr:
...         print isinstance(item, (tuple, list))
...         if isinstance(item, (tuple, list)):
...             lvl = 1 + depth(item)
...             if lvl >= d:
...                 d = lvl
...     return d
... 
>>> depth([['expt', 'x', 2]])
True
False
False
False
1
```

I suspect you are calling it with `depth(['expt', 'x', 2])` which gives

```
>>> depth(['expt', 'x', 2])
False
False
False
0
```

Comment: I will take a quick look at that to see if that is my issue when I am done eating. Idk how that could have happened. I didn't write the test cases after all, so I should inspect it

Comment: I am getting the correct answer as well when I run it in the shell. Hmmmmm. Well I will assume that I am right and their test cases are written wrong in some way. Do not want to reverse engineer their logic.

Comment: Maybe when they write `return [['expt', 'x', 2]]` they return a list of all the arguments to pass to your function, whish is only 1 in this case, so the argument they intend to pass is `['expt', 'x', 2]` and not ``['expt', 'x', 2]``

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the assignment and the `tests.py` file, I'm pretty sure it's calling your function with

```
apply(depth, depth_2_getargs())
```

rather than passing the result of `depth_2_getargs()` as a single argument. That's why it's called `getargs` instead of `getarg`. (`apply` is the old way of doing `*` and `**` arguments.)

The assignment states that an input like `['x']` should produce a result of 1, not 0. Your results are off by one. Also, you're not handling the case where the input isn't a list or tuple.

Comment: Ok I see now. Thank you. I will fix and update. I must have read that first example as a list lol. That's where my entire problem is

Comment: Problem was solved by adding `if isinstance(expr, (tuple, list)):
        d = 1` after `d = 0`